# SQL for getting distinct values and removing entries with specific sign does not work

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a simple table called Test with one column called ID. There are some strange ids in this table, these values contain a #. Furthermore there are duplicates in the table.

It looks like this:

[image]

I frist tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM Test
WHERE Test.ID NOT LIKE '%#%';
```

However, the entries with the # are still in.

I then tried to do one thing after another, so start with a simple query to remove these entries:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Test
WHERE Test.ID NOT LIKE '%#%';
```

This does not work? Why? How would a correct look like, to remove these entries which contain a # and remove the duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard for `LIKE` in MS Access is `*`, not `%`.  And so is `#` So try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM Test
WHERE Test.ID NOT LIKE '*[#]*';
```

Or:

```
WHERE INSTR(Test.ID, "#") > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, however when running this, the resulting table is empty?

Comment: When I just run "SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM Test;
" Then the distinct works, so it removes the duplicates, however still in are the entries with the strange sign, which I want to remove. So there must be something wrong with this where statement.

Answer (score 1):

The character `#` is a wildcard for LIKE in MS Access.
Use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM Test
WHERE ID NOT LIKE '*[#]*';
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use the ANSI-Like method, `ALIKE`, to continue using `%` for wildcard where `#` does not serve as an operator (requiring escaping):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM Test
WHERE ID NOT ALIKE '%#%';
```

Comment: And hopefully, one day soon MS Access will catch up to its database peers. Please encourage the Access team to update the dialect to current ANSI standards with this [post](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar) (upvote with no need to login)!